# Return an array with multiple responses with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a function that gets the exchange rates of some stocks:

```
export const getRates = (symbole1, symbole2, symbole3) => {
    
    const res = []

    axios.all([
        axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${symbole1}`),
        axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${symbole2}`),
        axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${symbole3}`)
    ])
        .then(axios.spread((data1, data2, data3) => {

            res.push(data1.data)
            res.push(data2.data)
            res.push(data3.data)
             return res
    }))
        .catch(
            err => console.log(err)
        )
}
```

Inside another file I use the function like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getRates('IBM', 'AAPL', 'MSFT')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setStock(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])
```

However, this doesn't work because the second file throws this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

What is the problem here? Can you not return the result like this? Or is there another problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you're asking for a promise resolve, but only returning a regular value. You could set up another promise to properly return something your `then` would understand - OR - you could just return the promise...

```
export const getRates = (symbole1, symbole2, symbole3) => {
  return axios.all([
    axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${symbole1}`),
    axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${symbole2}`),
    axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${symbole3}`)
  ])

}

useEffect(() => {
  const res = []
  getRates('IBM', 'AAPL', 'MSFT')
    .then(axios.spread((data1, data2, data3) => {
      res.push(data1.data)
      res.push(data2.data)
      res.push(data3.data)
      console.log(res)
      setStock(res)
    }))
    .catch(
      err => console.log(err)
    )

}, [])
```